# Need advise in merging dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, merge, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

**I am having 2 data frames as below. I would like to merge the two dataframes and display the match schedule with Match ID and Team names.**

```
df_team = pd.DataFrame({'Team_ID':['1','2','3','4'],'Team_Name':['CSK','KKR','MI','RCB']})
df_match = pd.DataFrame({'Match_id':['01','02','03','04'],'Team_ID':['1','2','3','4'],'Opponent_Team_Id':['2','3','4','1']})
display(df_team)
display(df_match)
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h84Hr.png)

**I got the expected output using the below code. However, I would like to know whether this could be simplified further. Please advise. Thanks in advance.**

*Merge to get Home team's name*

```
df_match_schedule = pd.merge(df_match,df_team,left_on='Team_ID',right_on='Team_ID')
df_match_schedule.rename(columns = {'Team_Name':'Home Team'}, inplace = True)
```

*Merge to get Away team's name*

```
df_match_schedule_2 = pd.merge(df_match_schedule,df_team,left_on='Opponent_Team_Id',right_on='Team_ID').drop('Team_ID_y',axis=1)
df_match_schedule_2.rename(columns = {'Team_Name':'Away Team'}, inplace = True)
```

*Display the match schedule*

```
df_match_schedule_2[['Match_id','Home Team','Away Team']]
```

[Final Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqsxn.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is mapping the Team IDs onto the name.

```
df_team = df_team.set_index("Team_ID")
df_match.loc[:,"Team_ID"] = df_match["Team_ID"].apply(lambda i: df_team.loc[i,"Team_Name"])
df_match.loc[:,"Opponent_Team_Id"] = df_match["Opponent_Team_Id"].apply(lambda i: df_team.loc[i,"Team_Name"])
```

(On a side note, your provided code does not work. The second merge.)
Also, when merging and both dataframes have the same column names you can use the keyword "on" instead of "right_on" and "left_on".